# Using several versions of qt-libs in single application

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

My main application was compiled by Qt V1 (ex. 4.7.4). (requires QtCore 4.7.4)
Shared library which main app uses was compiled by Qt V2 (ex.4.8.2). (requires QtCore 4.8.2)
I can't recompile library, and I don't want to recompile main app.
Is it possible to deploy my application with several versions of QtCore, QtGui etc.?

Comment: I don't know much about the specifics of this, but whenever I accidentally do it in OSX, I get tons of complaints about multiple Qt libs being loaded, and which one will be used at any time is undecided. I would think it could easily cause issues if one part of your code base calls into methods with the wrong API. Why can't you recompile your app against the available version of Qt?

Comment: Ok, suppose that I can recompile my app, but if I want to use several 3rd party libraries with different Qt-libs versions, how can I put them in one place?

Comment: Putting them in the same place isn't really the issue I think. They can link to the libs they need, but what happens when they all load and use the same namespaces? Is that a problem?

Comment: I want to make stand alone application. Copy of all dll's(for windows) with application, in same place. But one library(dll) needs QtCore4.dll(4.7.4), another QtCore4.dll(4.8.2). How can I put lib1 and lib2 in same folder with different version QtCore's?

Comment: Qt 4.7.x and Qt 4.8.x is not binary compatable.
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Version-Compatibility, but what need I do if I want to use binary non-compatable lib's in same place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to deploy my application with several versions of QtCore, QtGui etc.?

Short answer: no.

Long answer: *if* you planned for this in advance, you could have used the "shared library which uses Qt V2" (let's call int libFoo.so) indirectly via `dlopen` and `dlsym`. If you did do that, you could `dlopen("libFoo.so", RTLD_LOCAL)`, and then the symbols from "Qt V2" would not be visible to the main executable. This is a very shaky ground, but *in theory* it should work.